# Как выводить сообщение про ошибку?

Tags: symfony, symfony3

Не смог разобраться как просто вывести ошибку при валидации формы? Подскажите, пожалуйста:

Есть форма

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(),
                new Length(
                    [
                        'min' => 2,
                        'max' => 255,
                    ]
                ),
            ],
        ]);
    }
```

А тут если ошибки в форме, то вывести JsonResponse с текстом ошибки, $form->getErrors() возвращает пустоту.

Comment: а вы использовали в twig эту конструкцию? `{{ form_errors(form.name) }}`

Comment: @AntonKucenko, а мне для twig не нужно, только в json ответ отдать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У функции [getErrors](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormInterface.php#L106) есть два принимаемых параметра `deep` и `flatten`. Попробуйте использовать `deep = true`.

```
/**
 * Returns the errors of this form.
 *
 * @param bool $deep    Whether to include errors of child forms as well
 * @param bool $flatten Whether to flatten the list of errors in case
 *                      $deep is set to true
 *
 * @return FormErrorIterator An iterator over the {@link FormError}
 *                           instances that where added to this form
 */
public function getErrors($deep = false, $flatten = true);
```